# 109 bit tree comparator with generate and for loop

Tags: verilog, comparator

I am trying to write Verilog code for a 109-bit tree comparator, but I am still new to the generate loop.

[image: Here is the block diagram for the 109-bit tree comparator.]

I have written some code so far but I am not sure if this will work or if I can use 2-d arrays for g and l signals?

```
parameter NUM_OF_BITS = 220;
parameter NUM_OF_LEVELS = 7;
genvar i,x;

wire [NUM_OF_LEVELS:0][NUM_OF_BITS:0] g, l;

assign g[0] = in0;
assign l[0] = in1;

generate for (x=1; x<NUM_OF_LEVELS; x=x+1) begin: Ls
    for (i=0; i<NUM_OF_BITS/(2**x); i=i+1) begin: MCs
        mag_comp2_1 mc (g[x-1][2*i+1:2*i],l[x-1][2*i+1:2*i],g[x][i],l[x][i]);
    end
end
endgenerate

assign gt = g[7][0];
assign lt = l[7][0];
```

Comment: I am getting errors that `g is not a memory` & `l is not a memory`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The errors you are getting (`g is not a memory`) should point you to the issue which is that `g` is not correctly defined as a 2D array.

You declared your 2D arrays as:

```
wire [NUMBER_OF_ELEMENT-1:0][ELEMENT_WIDTH-1:0] name ;
```

Which is incorrect.

In Verilog, arrays are declared as:

```
wire [ELEMENT_WIDTH-1:0] name [NUMBER_OF_ELEMENT-1:0];
```

You declare the width of any element in a 2D array, then the name of the array, then the number of elements in the array **after** the name.